# Is it dangerous to live near lead?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, materials, toxicity, metallurgy

Several month ago, I soundproofed the door of my room with two sheets of lead. Can it be dangerous to live with them for many years? Can lead "decay" in some way and be inhaled? (and what happen when it oxidizes?)

Comment: i know they are similar, but i am more concerned with effects over a long period of time

Comment: Lead isn't a material that corrodes easily, lead sheets have been used for roofing, it lasts centuries, until stolen.  And since it isn't friable one would think the ingestion hazard is low.